# How to use 2 regex with one return?

Tags: regex, angular, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I writed a small regex with angular9 to observe if my route is `<website.url>/wiki/<id>` :

```js
  isWikiRoute(value?: string): boolean {
    return /^\/wiki(\/|$)/.test(value);
  }
```

This is working great.
Now, i'm trying to make the same function, but i need to observe this : `<website.url>/wiki/<id><?edit=1>`

```js
 isWikiRouteContribution(value?: string): boolean {
    return /^\/wiki(\/|$)/.test(value)./^\?edit=1(\/|$)/;
  }
```

But unfortunatly, this is not working.
It is possible to write 2 regex ? Do i need to use regexGroup ?

Edit (context) :

- I can read all the wiki content with mysite.com/wiki/<wiki_id>. In this page, you can make a contribution to the wiki. When i make a contribution at mysite.com/wiki/<wiki_id>, i add a slug to my router which is mysite.com/wiki/<wiki_id>?edit=1. I want to change the title on my toolbar when the slug is mysite.com/wiki/<wiki_id>?edit=1.

Comment: `but i need to observe this` ... how exactly are you trying to match two different things here?

Comment: Try: `return /^\/wiki(?:\/[^\/]+\?edit=1)?$/.test(value);`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm writing a wiki. I can read all the wiki content with mysite.com/wiki/<wiki_id>. In this page,  you can make a contribution to the wiki. When i make a contribution at mysite.com/wiki/<wiki_id>, i add a slug to my router which is mysite.com/wiki/<wiki_id>?edit=1. I want to change the title on my toolbar when the slug is mysite.com/wiki/<wiki_id>?edit=1.

Comment: @anubhava Hi! Thanks! But it return false everytime.. I'm sure im not that far to the solution

Comment: Check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/hRQij7/1 Regex is `/^\/wiki(?:\/[^\/]+\?edit=1|\/)?$/`

Comment: Thanks to @anubhava, the regex i wanted is : /^\/wiki(?:\/[^\/]+\?edit=1|\/)?$/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You can use this regex:

```
/^\/wiki(?:\/[^\/]+\?edit=1|\/)?$/
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\/wiki`: Match `/wiki`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\/`: Match a `/`
  - `[^\/]+`: Match 1 or more of any character except `/`
  - `\?`: Match a `?`
  - `edit=1`: Match `edit=1`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\/`: Match a `/`
- `)?`: End non-capture group and `?` makes whole group optional
- `$`: End

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hRQij7/1)

Comment: Regex superpower :)